# Numbered list in ReportLab

Tags: python, reportlab

I would like to print an indented, numbered list using reportlab.

What I want to print

> Welcome to my list
>
> 1. List item
> 2. List item
> 3. List item
>
> Thanks for reading

My reportlab template:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
canvas = canvas.Canvas("mypdf.pdf", pagesize=letter)
canvas.drawString(inch, inch, "Hello")
canvas.save()
```

I can't get the example from the reportlab user guide to work with my canvas. How can I print this list onto my pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following imports to the beginning of your script should resolve the errors you receive:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
```

Additionally, setting the *bottomup* parameter as shown below will start the text at the top right side of the page.

```
canvas = canvas.Canvas("mypdf.pdf", pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
```

The following example should create the PDF as you described:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

canvas = canvas.Canvas("mypdf.pdf", pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
items = [
    "List item one",
    "List item two",
    "List item three",
]
text_object = canvas.beginText(inch, inch)
text_object.textLine("Welcome to my list")
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    text_object.textLine("   {}. {}".format(index + 1, item))
text_object.textLine("Thanks or reading")
canvas.drawText(text_object)
canvas.save()
```